# largest three numbers from n numbers without using array

Tags: c, arrays, data-structures, max

I am in need to identify the greatest three elements from n numbers without using array, list like structure and I should not use any sorting logic.I done it something like this in C program. Is there any way to do it more efficiently?.

```
#include <stdio.h>
    int main()
    {
       int n;
       scanf("%d",&n);
       int number;
       scanf("%d",&number);
       int firstMax, secondMax, thirdMax;
       firstMax = secondMax = thirdMax =number;
       for(int i = 1; i<n ; i++){
           scanf("%d",&number);
           if(number > firstMax){
               thirdMax = secondMax;
               secondMax = firstMax;
               firstMax = number;
           }
           else if(number > secondMax){
               thirdMax = secondMax;
               secondMax = number;
           }
           else if(number > thirdMax){
               thirdMax = number;
           }
       }
       printf("%d %d %d",firstMax, secondMax, thirdMax);
       return 0;
    }
```

Comment: What are your performance concerns? Your algorithm runs n `O(n)`, which is optimal for this problem. If you want a general code review, you should look at [codereview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) instead.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is a request to help improve working code.

Comment: Since your code is working and you are only looking to make it better you should ask it to the Code Review.

Comment: @GomathiNatarajan.: What happens when your code get gets character input? Try checking return value of `scanf`.

Comment: This is really a code review question, but your approach seems reasonable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can start with comparing with `thirdMax`. If this is false, all others need not to be considered.

```
if (number > thirdMax)
{
    if (number > secondMax)
    {
        thirdMax = secondMax;
        if (number > firstMax )
        {
            secondMax = firstMax;
            firstMax = number;
        }
        else
        {
            secondMax = number;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        thirdMax = number;
    }
}
```